# Container-fluid padding is not working in css and navbar brand css not working

Tags: html, css

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>TinDog</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

    </head>

    <body>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <section id="title">
        <div class="container-fluid">


          <!-- Nav Bar -->
          <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
</section>
</body>

</html>



    .container-fluid
{
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-right: 150px;

}
.navbar-brand
{
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px:
}
```

The above CSS doesn't give padding to container-fluid, it takes the default padding, same behaviour when I give it in percentage adding even If I style the code within the HTML, the padding gets cancelled. Using container also doesn't improve the situation, the padding also gets cancelled. The code works in codeply.com but doesn't work in the atom. The font size of the navbar brand is also not changing, I tried all the values rem, px and %, then also it shows no change.[image: when I check the navbar brand font size it shows like this in chrome]

Comment: I don't see that you have used ".container-fluid" in your HTML code.

Comment: it is already in the code but doesn't appear, my bad. I edit the code and if not visible please consider it in a container-fluid class of bootstrap.

Comment: Try to take big digits for the padding and see what result is displaying

Comment: @burningknight have you included bootstrap in your project ? is bootstrap working

Comment: Make sure you have your custom CSS file loaded after the bootstrap css file. CSS that’s read by the browser will override the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Try to shift the bootstrap link above your styles.css file because that should be the hierarchical order. Default bootstrap styling will be applied then.

Answer (score 0):

You should try these steps -

1. Clear the browser's cookies and data
2. Try adding `!important` into css properties like below-

   `.container-fluid {
   padding-left: 150px !important;
   padding-right: 150px !important;
   }`

PS- Make sure you have included bootstrap into your code.

Answer (score -1):

Close your container-fluid  before section or after nav. You didn't close it.